# Why is Geoserver publishing my WMS layer in WGS84, when I have specified WyLAM?

Tags: geoserver, postgis-2.0

I am trying to publish a WMS layer from Geoserver, based on a table in a PostGIS dastabase.  The projection of the original source data is "WyLAM" (EPSG:8155).  It seems that no matter which options I select in the "Coordinate Reference Systems" boxes, the WMS gets published in WGS 84 (GCS_WGS_1984).  I have added the WyLAM projection to both Geoserver and PostGIS, since it's not included by default, but this did not seem to change anything.  For what it's worth, the layer displays in the correct location, so it seems that Geoserver *does* know that the source data are WyLAM.  How can I get the WMS to publish in WyLAM projection?

[image]

Comment: What do you see when you run GetCapabilities? By default GeoServer is publishing WMS layers in about 4000 projections as you can see from http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms?service=wms&version=1.3.0&request=getcapabilities. Do you mean that your GetCapabilities contains only one CRS?

Comment: No - GetCapabilities shows many projections, including the one I want (8155).  However, regardless of what option I select, the published layers are displaying in WGS84, by default.  When I pick a WyLAM layer to add to Geoserver, the Native SRS is blank.  With UTM Zone 12 NAD 83, it is not blank, but the resulting layer still shows up as WGS84 when added to ArcMap or QGIS.  Is this normal behavior?

Comment: The client is always telling what it wants by using a mandatory &SRS= or &CRS= parameters depending on the WMS version. Configure the projection of your QGIS of ArcMap into EPSG:8155 first and it will ask maps in EPSG:8155 from GeoServer.

Comment: OK -- I think I misunderstood how this works.  It sounds like the projection is set at the time of request on the client side, not by the projection that has been set in Geoserver.  Thus far, I've not been able to figure out how to change the request on the client side in either QGIS or ArcMap.  Both appear to default to WGS84, despite explicitly using "srs=EPSG:8155" in the request, and none of the settings I changed in the two packages themselves seemed to help.

Comment: The fifth image in http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/working_with_wms.html shows the "Coordinate reference system" section in the UI of QGIS. Press the "Change" button.

Comment: This seems to work OK in QGIS.  I am getting a strange error when I try the same in ArcMap -- "Too many coordinate systems."

Comment: Perhaps it can't parse the GetCapabilities with a list of more than 4000 SRS. Go to GeoServer admin utility, select Services - WMS and write a comma separated list of projections which are important for you into the Limited SRS list box.